# Не получается второй раз изменить фон Таббара

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Я использую команду:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:backGroundImageName];
```

Из делегата первый раз это срабатывает. Потом я из одного табВью пытаюсь вызвать ту же команду, но ничего не происходит.

Где поискать ошибку?

Comment: Метод вызываете в главном потоке?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то первый раз - да. Потом из ViewController.

Comment: В деталях происходит так: один из табов - прозрачный вид, в котором вызывается UIAction меню с выбором Темы оформления. При выборе темы я вызываю метод класса Тема "обновитьТему". Меняю разные параметры (тулбар, навбар). Все меняется, кроме фона табБара.

Comment: [[self.tabController tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:newBarImageBackGround]]; - сработало из нового открытого табВью. Но как это сделать глобально?

Comment: [UITabBar appearance] - это проскси обьект. Он участвует только при создании UI элементов, существующие не меняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кастомизация общая для всех UITabBar в приложении, достаточно вызвать это дело один раз, если нет, можно попробовать в разных классах вызывать

```
[[UITabBar appearanceWhenContainedIn: self, nil] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:backGroundImageName];
```

К тому же если у вас есть доступ напрямую к инстансу UITabBar, как к проперти, например:

```
self.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named:backgroundImageName)
```

лучше делать так, чем через appearance.